# How to use INSERT ON + UPDATE TRIGGER properly

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, insert

I have created SQLite tables named

- `Orders(OrderID, OrderDate, Total)` and another one named
- `OrderDetails(DetailID, OrderID(FK), Quantity, Price)`.

I am trying to use a `TRIGGER` that, when a new `DetailsOrder` is created (With the same IDOrder) would add the total of the prices of that order to the Total column at Orders.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger5 AFTER INSERT ON DetallesDeOrdenes
WHEN new.IDOrden
BEGIN
UPDATE Ordenes
SET Total = SUM(DetallesDeOrdenes.PrecioUnitario)
WHERE COUNT(DetallesDeOrdenes.IDOrden) => 2
END;
```

I know I have it completely wrong yet I cant figure out how to use TRIGGERS properly. Help would be much appreciated. PD Im a newbie at SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be able to look up the `OrderID` using `new.OrderID`.

Take a look at [this](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) documentation, especially

> INSERT **NEW** references are valid

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the editing! Still getting use to stackoverflow

Comment: Did this work for you? Do you need any further clarification?